# Change COM Port Number programmatically

Tags: windows, serial-port, com-port

In Device Manager, I can right click on a serial device, navigate to the Port Settings tab, click Advanced, and change the COM Port Number via a drop-down menu.

I need to automate this step across a large number of PCs. Is there a way to script this process, or to do it programmatically?

Comment: Are they all the same version of Windows?

Comment: They are not - could be WinXP, Win7, or Win8. Having said that, I'll happily accept a solution that only works on one (better than nothing!)

Comment: Hmmm....curious what is the specific application for this process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is probably best asked on [**stack*overflow***](https://stackoverflow.com/).  That said, take a look at [**ComDBReleasePort**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546477(v=vs.85).aspx) and [**ComDBClaimPort**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546472(v=vs.85).aspx) in the [**COM Port Database**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff546481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  However, changing COM port assignments programmaticly is not exactly considered a best practice.  For example, what happens if two more more concurrent applications are fighting to get the same COM assignment?

Windows dynamically assigns COM port numbers for a good reason.  Ideally, your application should be written so that it searches for the specific COM port it needs.  This can be done via polling or by using the [**Windows Management Interface (WMI)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

If you're referencing some application that someone else wrote, and you're just stuck with someone else's program design (or lack thereof), then you may want to consider adding a [**batch script to modify the registry**](http://ss64.com/nt/reg.html) key under `HKLM\Hardware\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM` at startup, since the new value(s) are not likely to hold between re-boots.

I don't know how how well this last option would work, but if you're a serious [**PowerShell**](http://powershell.com/cs/) or [**Python**](https://www.python.org/) user, you could theoretically use either scripting language to directly access the APIs mentioned at the beginning of my response for a one-time COM port re-assignment.